# Ajax: add a variable to a formData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I got a jQuery script which sends info about a picture to a php file through a "formData" variable, like this:

```
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: "POST",
    contentType:false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){}
```

As far as I know, here is the part of the script that generates the content of that formData before it is sent:

```
function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', files[i]);
        var status = new createStatusbar(obj);
        status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name,files[i].size);
        sendFileToServer(fd,status);
    }
}
```

To catch that data in the php file, I just use

```
$_FILES['file'][...];
```

What I would like to do is to simultaneously send an additional javascript variable to the php file, along with the formData, that I would be able to catch as

```
$_POST['picID'];
```

How would I do that?

Thank you.

PS the additional javascript variable "picID" is defined at the beginning of the root of the js file so, it should normally be accessible from within any function in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append as many `key` => `value` to the form data.

```
fd.append('key',  value);
```

Applying to your scenario,

```
fd.append('picID', value); //where value is the value of picID
```

I would recommend that you declare the form data variable `fd` before the `for` loop begins. This is because only the file data requires the loop.  For additional form data, append them outside the loop

Example

```
function handleUpload(){
var fd = new FormData();
//commence for loop {

  // }end for loop
   //append extra key => value 
  fd.append('key', value); 
   }
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thanks. As a matter of fact, I did something similar by try and guess but with no success. But this is a strong lead in the way I should format it. I'll try and come back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Pleasure. Try it out

Comment: It worked, thanks. That's exactly what I did in the first place but with a major error, I put that instruction inside the loop. For whatever reason, it didn't work. but outside the loop, it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure friend :)